# Curl request to pod IP in kubernetes cluster refused

Tags: kubernetes

I have a k8s cluster with such services:

```
    $ kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME                                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP            NODE                         NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
oauth2-proxy-example-0              1/1     Running   2          13m   10.244.0.12   oauth2-proxy-control-plane   <none>           <none>
oauth2-proxy-example-postgresql-0   1/1     Running   0          13m   10.244.0.15   oauth2-proxy-control-plane   <none>           <none>
```

Curl to IP is refused for some reason for e.g from other pod:

```
   curl -v 10.244.0.12:80 -o /dev/nul
* Expire in 0 ms for 6 (transfer 0x56369b6b0f50)
*   Trying 10.244.0.12...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x56369b6b0f50)
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* connect to 10.244.0.12 port 80 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to 10.244.0.12 port 80: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.244.0.12 port 80: Connection refused


 kubectl get pods oauth2-proxy-example-0  -o yaml
```

https://pastebin.com/v6yRV0nM - that is the output (sorry to big to include it directly here)

What might be the issue with curl this pod IP?

Comment: curl is being done from inside or outside the cluster?

Comment: @ArghyaSadhuI recreated my cluster and made new curl from inside on po to other and got this
https://pastebin.com/Urcd4Mjz Updated description

Comment: the app running as pod need to listen on port 80 using interface 0.0.0.0 instead of 12.0.0.1

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu I'm sorry  but where is it 12.0.0.1 described? Don't quite understand :(

Comment: My bad it should be 127.0.0.1...not 12.0.0.1

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu from the begging of logs of app I see that it's 0.0.0.0, that's strange https://pastebin.com/PqSPwQ5R

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220771/discussion-between-arghya-sadhu-and-xell).

Comment: Its your local env or cloud? From where to where are you trying to curl? Did you set any firewall rules?

Comment: @PjoterS it is local..i think there is no port forwarding to app port maybe

Comment: But what you want to achieve? Do you want to curl from 1 pod to another in the same cluster? You want to curl pod from outside the cluster? Are you using any `NodePort`, `LoadBalancer` or `Ingress`?